# Export CEWP as .webpart file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-editor-web-part

I'm trying to export my Content Editor webpart from SP2013 environment, and I expect output file in .webpart format. Currently I'm getting output file in .dwp format.

Any idea how to get Content Editor webpart in .webpart format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you getting the *.dwp file which basically a XML. Content editor is not behaves like *.webpart. 
What you can be done is export the file as its and import in the visual studio in a empty module. Deploy it..it will be visible in the web parts section. I hope after then you know what to do.

Following post would be useful:
[How to add content editor web part to webpart gallery| Export content editor web part (OOTB in SharePoint)](https://kushanlahiru.wordpress.com/2016/05/31/how-to-add-content-editor-web-part-to-webpart-gallery-export-content-editor-web-part-ootb-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Please do not post any link which does not help to answer the question. Rather you can add your website link in your profile

Answer (score 2):

You can just rename .dwp to .webpart and use it.